# PHP Notice: Undefined offset: 4

Tags: php

I'm getting the following error

PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 4 -- LINE 190

in the chunk of code below.  I've tried a couple different solutions that I found here including isset, but nothing seems to work.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
// If we don't have any data get it from the db

$GLOBALS['AKB_CLASS_HELPER']->getCatsInfo();
$parentid = 0;

if (!empty($arrCats[0])) {
            foreach ($arrCats as $cat) {
                foreach ($GLOBALS['AKB_CLASS_HELPER']->tree->nodesByPid[$parentid] as $catid) {  <--------- LINE190
                    $pcat = $GLOBALS['AKB_CLASS_HELPER']->catsById[$catid];
                    if (strtolower($pcat['name']) == strtolower($cat)) {
                        $GLOBALS['CatTrails'][] = array ($pcat['categoryid'], $cat);
                        $this->_catId = $pcat['categoryid'];
                        $parentid = $pcat['categoryid'];
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: is $GLOBALS['AKB_CLASS_HELPER']->tree->nodesByPid[$parentid] traversable?

Comment: Check that the value of `$parentid` is being set correctly.

Comment: $parentId = 4 and that isn't a defined offset in the array you are snooping.

Comment: I edited my original post to show $parentid above